# How to find and replace a string in a file using windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

What is the easy way to find and replace a string in a file using windows batch file?

Comment: I typed some of the keywords from the question into Google and got a bunch of promising-looking results, many of them answers to questions on *this very site*. Have you tried searching for a solution to your problem first? What code have you written? Did it not work?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature out of the box, so you need to use third-party tool such as [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)